# How to get a product value attribute from attribute id?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, catalog, model

I need to retrieve product attribute value based on the attribute id, here's how I get the id and label for each attribute

```
$attributes= Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')->getItems();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
   $id[] = $attribute->getAttributecode();
   $label[] = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product','color');
echo $attributeModel->getStoreLabel($storeId);
```

If you want to get any attribute value of any product ;

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo $_product->getData($attributeCode);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**Retrieve product attribute value based on the attribute code**

```
<?php
   $attributeCode = "size";
   $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);
   $options = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
            ->setAttribute($attribute)
            ->getAllOptions(false);

   foreach ($options as $option) {
        echo $option['label']." => ".$option['value']."<br>";
   }
?>
```

**Retrieve product attribute value based on the attribute id**

```
<?php
  $attributeId = 198;
  $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attributeId);
  $options = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_source_table')
            ->setAttribute($attribute)
            ->getAllOptions(false);

   foreach ($options as $option) {
        echo $option['label']." => ".$option['value']."<br>";
   }
?>
```